# Rest of page not scrolling down

Tags: html, css

[image]i have come across a problem that i cant seem to solve,
on my 23" monitor the page shows the content, how ever on my laptop screen 14" it does not show all the content, i can scroll a bit but not all the way to see the res of the page, any thugs?

```css
    body {
     font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
     background-color: #141414;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 90%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     
    }

    img#logo {
     width: 250px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 10px;
     border: none;
     
    }

    div#nav {
     background-color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.7);
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #000;
     height: 70px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     
    }

    div#division {
     margin-top: 120px;
    }

    .octo {
     position: fixed;
     right: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .wraper {
     margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
     width: 1200px;
     padding-left: 100px;

     
    }

    .poster {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 273px;

    }

    figure {

     background-color: rgba(106, 192, 69, 0.7);
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding-left: 3px;
    }

    img {
     
    }

    figcaption {
     font-weight: bold;
     padding-left: 5px;
    }

    figure:hover {
     background-color: #1ba6e0;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Rewind HD</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/rewind hd.css">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="nav">
     <img id="logo" src="images/REWIND HD web.png">
    </div>
    <div id="division"></div>

     <div class="wraper">

     <div class="poster">
     <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Octopussy</figcaption>
      <a href="james Bond.html"><img src="images/octopussy.jpg"></a>
     </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> A View To A Kill</figcaption>
      <a href="james Bond A view to kill.html"><img src="images/JBAVTK.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> For Your Eyes Only</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond For Your Eyes Only.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Majestys Secret Service</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond On Her Majestys Secret Service.html"><img src="images/James Bond On Her Majestys Secret Service.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> The Living Daylights</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond The Living Daylights.html"><img src="images/James Bond The Living Daylights.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> The Spy Who Loved</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond The Spy Who Loved.html"><img src="images/James Bond The Spy Who Loved.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>ames Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg" class="background_color"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>ames Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
      </figure>
     </div>

     <div class="poster">
      <figure>
      <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
      <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg" 

     </figure>
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
***strong text***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:
first, change `width` of `wrapper` to `85%` for have fluid wrapper.
then add `float:left` to `.poster` class.
the code is here ( you have a little responsive page):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Rewind HD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/rewind hd.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>



    body {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color: #141414;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 90%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    img#logo {
        width: 250px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 10px;
        border: none;

    }

    div#nav {
        background-color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.7);
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #000;
        height: 70px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;

    }

    div#division {
        margin-top: 120px;
    }

    .octo {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .wraper {
        margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        width: 85%;
        padding-left: 100px;


    }

    .poster {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 273px;
         float:left;

    }

    figure {

        background-color: rgba(106, 192, 69, 0.7);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding-left: 3px;
    }

    img {

    }

    figcaption {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    figure:hover {
        background-color: #1ba6e0;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }







        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="nav">
        <img id="logo" src="images/REWIND HD web.png">
    </div>
    <div id="division"></div>

        <div class="wraper">

        <div class="poster">
        <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Octopussy</figcaption>
            <a href="james Bond.html"><img src="images/octopussy.jpg"></a>
        </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> A View To A Kill</figcaption>
            <a href="james Bond A view to kill.html"><img src="images/JBAVTK.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> For Your Eyes Only</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond For Your Eyes Only.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Majestys Secret Service</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond On Her Majestys Secret Service.html"><img src="images/James Bond On Her Majestys Secret Service.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> The Living Daylights</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond The Living Daylights.html"><img src="images/James Bond The Living Daylights.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> The Spy Who Loved</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond The Spy Who Loved.html"><img src="images/James Bond The Spy Who Loved.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>ames Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg" class="background_color"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>ames Bond<br /> Licence To Kill</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond For your eyes only.html"><img src="images/James Bond Licence To Kill.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Moonraker</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Moonraker.html"><img src="images/James Bond Moonraker.jpg"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            <figure>
            <figcaption>James Bond<br /> Never Say Never Again</figcaption>
            <a href="James Bond Never Say Never Again.html"><img src="images/James Bond Never Say Never Again.jpg" 

        </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: Im glad I could be of assistance.but is that answer, you want?

Comment: so if that was your answer.please accept the answer.